# Is there anyway to shorten if else statements instead of going in circles

Tags: java, if-statement, statements

I have a cat that runs across the screen and stops to scratch in the middle of the screen twice. My current code looks like

```
private void scratch(){
for (int i = xPos; i < getWidth(); i+=0) {
    xPos = i;
    // swap images
    if (currentImage == nekoPics[0]) 
        currentImage = nekoPics[2];
    else if (currentImage == nekoPics[2])
        currentImage = nekoPics[4];
    else if (currentImage == nekoPics[4])
        currentImage = nekoPics[5];
    else if (currentImage == nekoPics[5])
        currentImage = nekoPics[4];
    else if (currentImage == nekoPics[4]) 
        currentImage = nekoPics[5];
    else 
        currentImage = nekoPics[0]
```

Is there an easier way to make the if else statements than have them going in a huge circle like this?

Thanks in advance
(PS : I assume you could do this with a counter of some sort, but I wasn't so sure on how to go about this, any help is appreciated)

Comment: you can use `switch-case`.

Comment: what does i+=0 means????

Comment: the 5th `if` will always evaluate to false because you checked it in the 3rd `if`.

Comment: Try a dictionary, instead of if/else simply access the location in the dict.

Answer (score 2):

You may keep the index of the current image, and increment it on each iteration, for instance:

```
currentImage = nekoPics[currentIndex%6];
currentIndex++;
```

or

```
currentImage = nekoPics[currentIndex];
if (++currentIndex==6) currentIndex=0;
```

This requires that images in nekoPics be sorted according to the order of the animation.

Comment: did this, works out alright, this is one method, how to i get this to like stop running and let the other method start running so the cat will run to the end of the screen again after it scratches? Basically it starts running with public void moveIn, then gets to scratch then i have a moveOut method also to make it run to the end, but i can't get this to start after its finished going through the scratches

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a Map suggested elsewhere, you could just use an array; you'll need to keep track of the index of the current image:

```
int[5] nextImageList
  = { 2, ?, 4, 5, 4 }

next = nextImageList[currentImageIndex];
currentImage = nekoPics[next];
currentImageIndex = next;
```

No 'if' needed after you initialize currentImage and currentImageIndex.  I wasn't sure if 1 was a valid index anywhere, if not, anything can go in the 1 slot in the array.

Comment: Probably the simplest answer for beginners. I suggested an edit, as the array is composed of (at least) 6 slots, not 5. The third slot is also unknown.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to code if you stop that cat from getting in front of your screen...

Seriously, though, you could solve this by making an object that defines your sequence of pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post an answer similar to [rcook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1013112/rcook), using an array. I see it as the simplest solution to understand.

His answer, however, has a slight mistake concerning the array dimensions. I'm posting this for completeness, but credit should be directed to him.

```
// Elsewhere, in your initialization:
int currentImageIndex = 0; // Assuming [0] is your first image.
int[] nextImageList = { 2, -1, 4, -1, 5, 4 };
// Given the current index, this array will direct you
// to the next image index. Those -1 are unknown (to us).
// Set them to the values you need.

private void scratch() {
    for (int i = xPos; i < getWidth(); ) {
        xPos = i;

        // Swap images.
        currentImageIndex = nextImageList[currentImageIndex];
        currentImage = nekoPics[currentImageIndex];

        // What else you were doing here.
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks is really actually helped work this one out, cheers man