# How to shorten an if else statement in java?

Tags: java, if-statement

*Note:Keep in mind that im a newbie both at java and stackoverflow and this is my first question.*

Okay, so I was making a basic console based game in java and 
I had a problem. I had a long list of if else statements. How I can shorten them?
I have tried looking at [Is there anyway to shorten if else statements instead of going in circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001651/is-there-anyway-to-shorten-if-else-statements-instead-of-going-in-circles) but i didn't get the answer I needed.
Here's some sample code from my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FishMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FishClass myFish = new FishClass();

    //Makes a scanner for user input/commands
    Scanner userComSc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //scans for what the user types
    String userCom = userComSc.nextLine();

    //checks if the userCommand isn't /end or exit (when it is it will terminate)
    while(!userCom.equals("/end") && !userCom.equals("/exit")) {

         if(userCom.equals("/dive 1")){
            myFish.dive(1); 
        }
        else if(userCom.equals("/dive 2")){
            myFish.dive(2);
        }
        else if(userCom.equals("/dive 3")){
            myFish.dive(3);

        } else if
           //so on till 99...

   }
```

I have tried something like this:

```
if(userCom.startsWith("/dive")){
     int howDeep = Integer.parseInt(userCom);
     myFish.dive(howDeep);
}
```

but it ends up in an error. Here's the error message:

```
//user types
/dive 6
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/dive 6"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at FishMaster.main(FishMaster.java:40)
```

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Edit 1 : Sorry for the confusion of the "/dive 1" (ft) making myFish dive 3ft, that was a typo it is now fixed...

Comment: Is there supposed to be a pattern here? `/dive 1` produces a `dive(3)` call, and I'm not sure what `dive(a)` is supposed to be.

Comment: they exceptions says it right there. You're trying to parse a string with non numeric characters.

Comment: The problem with that idea is that you're trying to convert "/dive 6" into an integer, which it isn't. You need to extract just the integer part.

Comment: Do you know what version of java you are using. In java7 you can `switch` with `String`s

Comment: I guess this is what you need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338790/get-int-from-string-also-containing-letters-in-java

Integer.parseInt(t.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""))

Comment: @user2357112 im sorry i have corrected the errors... i had some messy code.:P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That was a good idea, unfortunately, you are trying to parse a string with non-numeric characters as an int. You need to substring the Int from the string like so:

```
if(userCom.startsWith("/dive")){
   String str = userCom.subString(6);
   int howDeep = Integer.parseInt(str);
   myFish.dive(howDeep);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 7, `switch` statement supports `String` constants, so your code can become:

```
switch (userCom) {
    case "/dive 1":
        //...
        break;
    case "/dive 2":
        //...
        break;
    case "/dive 3":
        //...
        break;
    //and on...
}
```

A better approach would be storing the data in a `Map<String, Object>` so you seek for your specific data using the `userCom` as key:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("/dive 1", ...);
data.put("/dive 2", ...);
data.put("/dive 3", ...);
//...
myFish.dive(data.get(userCom));
```

In case your unique command is */dive ${arg}*, then it would be better to remove the */dive * before parsing the statement:

```
String singleArgument = userCom.substring(userCom.indexOf(' '));
//singleArgument value is the number after */dive *
```

Note that approach above will work **only** if your object receives the specific value of the argument after */dive*. I note this because you have stated in your code sample:

```
if(userCom.equals("/dive 1")){
    myFish.dive(3); 
}
```

So parsing "1" won't give you 3.

Comment: But then it's 100 `case` lines or 100 `data.put` lines. Not a practical way to parse an integer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a bug :)

Comment: @DanielDarabos "/dive 3" => a. Still unsure about a typo. Anyway, OP asked for a possible solution, I provide such. It shouldn't like to everybody :)

Comment: @DanielDarabos @LuiggiMendoza umm so sorry but i had some mistakes in my code so it meant to be `if(userCom.equals("/dive 1")){ myFish.dive(1)}`

Answer (score 0):

You could make a small edit to parse only the numeric part of your string with a small modification to your first attempt at parsing an int from the string

```
if(userCom.startsWith("/dive ")){
 String intPart = userCom.split(' ')[1]; // get just the number part of the string
 int howDeep = Integer.parseInt(intPart); // parse the 'number' to an int
 myFish.dive(howDeep);}
```

In reality you don't have to create `intPart` as a separate variable and could just put it into the `parseInt` method as an argument. The key is to split the string at the space and take the second part only to parse. This should eliminate the error that arises when parsing the string into an int at least.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are programming in Java, I think it would be better to use an Object-oriented design.
A good pattern to use, when transforming a large switch-case or long if-else-if structure, is to encapsulate the behavior in a class-structure. In your case, a naive approach would be to have classes Dive1, Dive2, Dive3, ... A more fitting design would have a Dive class with a distance field. These would be UserCommand classes. They would probably have an execute(Fish f) method, that would apply the desired behavior to the fish.
Now we can also isolate the logic to create the appropriate UserCommand for each input that the user types. This could be done by the UserCommandFactory. It would have a create(String input) method, that would parse the input and create the correct object.
This design seems more complex at first, but it is much more flexible and less error prone.

Comment: Thanks for the info but i just wanted a shortcut.